# Using $.data() in jQuery to store flag on element

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I am authoring a simple jQuery plugin that turns an input tag into a time-formatted element (on blur it will change 245p into 2:45 pm).

Since I do not want to apply the time format events to the same element twice, I need a way to detect that the specific element in the list provided has not already had the format applied.

This is the relevant part of the code:

```
var methods = {
    init : function(sel) {
        var $this = $(sel);
        return $this.each(function(){
            var data = $(this).data('time_formatted');
            if (data) {
                return;
            } else {
                $(this).data('time_formatted', true);
```

I have heard that using `$(sel).data()` in a plugin is not a good idea; instead, use `$.data()`. I don't know why, that's just what I've heard; honestly, I don't know what the difference is.

So my question is, is this the way to accomplish checking if a specific element has had the time formatter applied to it in a plugin?

If you care to see the plugin in it's current development state, see http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/xhXCR/.

Thanks!

Jared

Comment: Hmm... This looks like a nice plugin Jared! Kudos.

Comment: Thanks. I woman I work with wouldn't stop complaining about having to type the `:` in the time... I want to do a suite of plugins based on formatting, for instance, phone numbers, credit card numbers, etc...

Comment: Nice plugin, add support for `.`, like `10.30` and I will start using it if it is open

Comment: This particular plugin needs an overhaul, something I still have started. I'll let you know when I get it done. `:)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Where have you heard that using `.data()` is not good? [jQuery's plugin autoring](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring#Data) page says:

> Often times in plugin development, you may need to maintain state or check if your plugin has already been initialized on a given element. Using jQuery's `data` method is a great way to keep track of variables on a per element basis. However, rather than keeping track of a bunch of separate data calls with different names, it's best to use a single object literal to house all of your variables, and access that object by a single data namespace.

So it should be perfectly fine.

Comment: Not to use the form `$(sel).data()`; instead, `$.data()` in a plugin is what I've heard. I just can't see how I can effectively do what I want using `$.data()`. I edited the question with a clarification.

Comment: @JaredFarrish: It is the same. `$(sel).data()` is the same as `$.data($(sel)[0])` (assuming `$(sel)` only selects one element. `$.data` is more low level. There really is not a big difference.

Comment: If there isn't a difference, that's great. I sure prefer the former to the latter, since it seems to make the most sense to me.

Comment: I guess now, is it accomplishing adding a `time_formatted` flag that is specific to that element?

Comment: Well, it appears to. Thanks Felix.

Comment: @JaredFarrish: I don't understand. But if you figured it out, great ;) You're welcome :)

Comment: This was throwing me: "Prior to jQuery 1.4.3 (starting in jQuery 1.4) the .data() method completely replaced all data, instead of just extending the data object. If you are using third-party plugins it may not be advisable to completely replace the element's data object, since plugins may have also set data." http://api.jquery.com/data/

Comment: All I want is that the specific element in the loop run on methods.init() will check that that specific element has that time_formatted data set to true, and it wouldn't give a false positive/negative on another element.

Comment: @JaredFarrish: I see. That just means if you pass an object to  `.data`, like `.data({foo: 'bar'})`, then all the data was overridden.

Comment: @JaredFarrish: That is fine. As you are looping over each element, you are only setting the data for one element at a time.